# Fechar o teclado IOS ao clicar confirmar

Tags: swift

como faço para que o teclado suma quando eu clicar em um botão confirmando aquele nome que esta no textbox?

Eu quero que quando eu clicar no botao confirmar jogador o teclado suma, pois ele continua aparecendo cortando a metade da tela onde está o jogo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não pressiona o **return** do teclado no campo, você não tem o `textField` em que ocorreu o evento. Logo você precisa dizer que a `view` não está mais sendo editada, da seguinte maneira:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Outra maneira de fazer isso, quando você conhece o campo que foi editado (normalmente quando se tem apenas um na tela você pode fazer isso), seria:

```
txtName.resignFirstResponder()
```

Onde `txtName` é o nome do seu `textField`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Muito obrigado!